# does aws EMR version 5.23.0 support python version 3.7.x?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-emr

Currently we are using EMR version 5.23.0 to submit our pyspark jobs.
We want to upgrade python version to 3.7 and wanted to check if python 3.7 is supported on current EMR version 5.23.0.
There is no official information available on AWS about version compatibility.
Can anybody please help me to find out this information

Answer (score 1):

From experiment, Python 3.7 is supported on EMR in version 5.30.x and version 6.0 with PySpark associated with it through the config:

```
'spark.pyspark.python', 'python3'
```

Comment: can you please share the source for this ? - link ?

Comment: It was a an enterprise support ticket as I couldn't find the info on the public AWS docs.

Answer (score 1):

Currently EMR comes with python v3.6.x

But I'll suggest not to replace python v3.6.x. install [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) during [bootstrap](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html).
Miniconda can give you freedom to choose python version.

Install libraries using `conda install <library-name>`.
But **do not** install `pyspark`, it will be already there with all the configuration. Installing pyspark separately will cause issue with configuration.

You can also create your own AMI with all pre-installed. This will reduce your bootstrap time.

**For *pyspark* shell:**
Add these 2 environment variable

```
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/<path-miniconda-home>/bin/python
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/<path-miniconda-home>/bin/python
```

**For *spark-submit*:**
Add these configuration

```
--conf spark.executorEnv.PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/<path-miniconda-home>/bin/python
--conf spark.executorEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=/<path-miniconda-home>/bin/python
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/<path-miniconda-home>/bin/python
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=/<path-miniconda-home>/bin/python
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it comes with 3.6 as of [version 5.20](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-whatsnew-history.html).

You could of course modify this, but it won't be guaranteed.